# Where to find which library belongs a class?

Tags: java, class

I wonder if there is any page where I could write a class name, for instance

> javax.faces.view.facelets.TagHandler

And tells me in which .jar is included. Because as I can see in this class [documentation](http://www.jarvana.com/jarvana/view/org/apache/myfaces/core/myfaces-api/2.0.2/myfaces-api-2.0.2-javadoc.jar!/javax/faces/view/facelets/TagHandler.html) this information is not included.

EDIT: using your pages, http://www.findjar.com/ or http://www.jarfinder.com/ I don't find the class. Can anybody help me on this??
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out thats: jsf-api-2.0.jar

you can download this jar here

http://download.java.net/maven/2/javax/faces/jsf-api/2.0/

Answer (score 1):

There is http://www.jarfinder.com/ , but if you have the library in your project, you can open it in your IDE and it will show where it belongs.

For this particular class - it is part of mojarra (JSF-RI) - [see here](http://www.docjar.com/projects/Mojarra-2.0.1-java.html)

Answer (score 1):

Use [findjar.com](http://findjar.com)

Answer (score 1):

[findjar.com](http://findjar.com) does that. But it can't find this class.

Answer (score 1):

I'd try http://www.docjar.com/ . It [finds one result](http://www.docjar.com/docs2web/s.jsp?q=javax.faces.view.facelets.TagHandler&t=j&start=0) for your class.